# Set java path on CentOS 7.x

Tags: bash, java, path

I have a java application running on my CentOS VM. Originally the java path could be supplied in an application startup script, not good to hard code values in a file. I checked the Redhat site how to set the path variable for the bash shell:

Bash Shell

Edit the startup file (~/.bashrc) Modify PATH variable

PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH
export PATH

Save and close the file Load the startup file

% . /.profile

1) The java application is run by a specific user that has been setup correctly on the system. I have added a systemd script to start the application as root:

systemctl start

2) I have added the above mentioned path information to the “user’s” and to the “root” user’s ~/.bashrc files However, there is no individual /.profile file for neither of the users. There is only the: /etc/profile File

3) When I ran $ java -version It still lists the default java version that came with the OS image and not the java version that I downloaded

My question is, to be able to set the Java path correctly, do I have to create a user specific ~/.profile File so that the correct java version is found. I tried that but still no luck with getting the correct java version path set

Here is the .service file (/etc/systemd/system)

```
[Unit]
Description=<application-name>
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/<path>/<to_app>/<application_name> start
ExecStop=/<path>/<to_app>/<application_name> stop
Type=simple
PIDFile=/<path>/<to_app>/<application_name>/.tmp/<application_name>.pid
User=<user_name>
WorkingDirectory=/<path>/<to_app>/<application_name>
TimeoutStartSec=1000

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Any thoughts?

Cheers, Roland

Comment: I am confused, and don't understand what you actually want to achieve. `PATH` is just the search path for binaries you execute on Linux. There are additional variables for Java, like `CLASSPATH` and `JAVA_HOME`. You can find out which binary is selected for a given `PATH` by using `which java`. If you start something via `systemd`, then I am not sure if it will actually execute `~/.bashrc`, unless you explicitely start `bash`. If the problem is using `systemd`, please edit the question and say so.

Comment: If it's `systemd`: Is anything stopping you from just giving the full path in whatever `systemd` configuration file you are using? And please include the contents of this file in the question.

Comment: in an older version of the application we could set the 
```
JAVA_HOME=<<path>/<to>/<java>/bin
```  
in the application startup script. 
In the newer version I still have to set:
```    
JAVA_HOME=<path>/<to>/<java>/bin
```
And one way to to that manually was to use the java command line tool
According to direct it should also be possible to set it directly in the system file
Enviroment="JAVA_HOME=<path>/<to>/<java>/bin"

Cheers,
Roland